# how to assign role to registered users in asp.net core mvc 6

Tags: asp.net, identity, asp.net5

How can I do Assign role to registered users?
im using this code but i receive error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbY2m.png)

---

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "user");
                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
                    // Send an email with this link
                    //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    //var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                    //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account",
                    //    $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
```

---

my roles in database:
[roles][2]

Comment: You should include the details of the error in your post here, not rely on an image hosted elsewhere

Comment: thanks for helping error image :http://img.majidonline.com/pic/320442/2017-03-08%20(2).png

Comment: You should include the details of the error in your post here, not rely on an image hosted elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

```
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "user");
```

Bro, put this before `return` and after:

```
_logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password");
```